# StartService fails with error code 1053

Tags: c++, windows, remoting

I'm trying to start a process on a remote machine. I'm using OpenSCManager(), CreateService(), QueryServiceStatusEx() and StartService() API-s. I'm able to successfully install my process as a serice, but when i'm trying to start it, StartService returns with errorocode 1053 ("The service didn't respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."). Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

kampi

Update: Here's my code so far(almost from msdn, but i have edited a bit)

```
#include <windows.h>
VOID SvcInstall();  
VOID __stdcall DoStartSvc();  

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")  
SC_HANDLE schSCManager;  
SC_HANDLE schService;  

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
SvcInstall();
DoStartSvc();

return 0;
}

VOID SvcInstall()
{
SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
SC_HANDLE schService;
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

if( !GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH ) )
{
    printf("Cannot install service (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Get a handle to the SCM database. 

schSCManager = OpenSCManager( 
    _T("\\\\kampimachine"),  // remote computer
    NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

if (NULL == schSCManager) 
{
    printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Create the service
schService = CreateService( 
    schSCManager,              // SCM database 
    _T("kampi"),                   // name of service 
    _T("kampi"),                   // service name to display 
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access 
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type 
    SERVICE_DEMAND_START,      // start type 
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      // error control type 
    _T("%SystemRoot%\\system32\\notepad.exe"),// path to service's binary 
    NULL,                      // no load ordering group 
    NULL,                      // no tag identifier 
    NULL,                      // no dependencies 
    _T("domain\\user"),    // LocalSystem account 
    _T("password"));          // no password 

if (schService == NULL) 
{
    printf("CreateService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return;
}
else printf("Service installed successfully\n"); 

CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}

VOID __stdcall DoStartSvc()
{
SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssStatus; 
DWORD dwOldCheckPoint; 
DWORD dwStartTickCount;
DWORD dwWaitTime;
DWORD dwBytesNeeded;

// Get a handle to the SCM database. 

schSCManager = OpenSCManager( 
    _T("\\\\kampimachine"),       // remote computer
    NULL,                    // servicesActive database 
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

if (NULL == schSCManager) 
{
    printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Get a handle to the service.

schService = OpenService( 
    schSCManager,         // SCM database 
    _T("kampi"),            // name of service 
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access 

if (schService == NULL)
{ 
    printf("OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return;
}    

// Check the status in case the service is not stopped. 

if (!QueryServiceStatusEx( 
        schService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
        (LPBYTE) &ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded ) )              // size needed if buffer is too small
{
    printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return; 
}

// Check if the service is already running. It would be possible 
// to stop the service here, but for simplicity this example just returns. 

if(ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED && ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
{
    printf("Cannot start the service because it is already running\n");
    CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return; 
}

// Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

// Wait for the service to stop before attempting to start it.

while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
{
    // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
    // one-tenth of the wait hint but not less than 1 second  
    // and not more than 10 seconds. 

    dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

    if( dwWaitTime < 1000 )
        dwWaitTime = 1000;
    else if ( dwWaitTime > 10000 )
        dwWaitTime = 10000;

    Sleep( dwWaitTime );

    // Check the status until the service is no longer stop pending. 

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx( 
            schService,                     // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
            (LPBYTE) &ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded ) )              // size needed if buffer is too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return; 
    }

    if ( ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint )
    {
        // Continue to wait and check.

        dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
        dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
    }
    else
    {
        if(GetTickCount()-dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
        {
            printf("Timeout waiting for service to stop\n");
            CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
            CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
            return; 
        }
    }
}

// Attempt to start the service.

if (!StartService(
        schService,  // handle to service 
        0,           // number of arguments 
        NULL) )      // no arguments 
{
    printf("StartService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return; 
}
else printf("Service start pending...\n"); 

// Check the status until the service is no longer start pending. 

if (!QueryServiceStatusEx( 
        schService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // info level
        (LPBYTE) &ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded ) )              // if buffer too small
{
    printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return; 
}

// Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING) 
{ 
    // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
    // one-tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no 
    // more than 10 seconds. 

    dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

    if( dwWaitTime < 1000 )
        dwWaitTime = 1000;
    else if ( dwWaitTime > 10000 )
        dwWaitTime = 10000;

    Sleep( dwWaitTime );

    // Check the status again. 

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx( 
        schService,             // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, // info level
        (LPBYTE) &ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded ) )              // if buffer too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        break; 
    }

    if ( ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint )
    {
        // Continue to wait and check.

        dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
        dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
    }
    else
    {
        if(GetTickCount()-dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
        {
            // No progress made within the wait hint.
            break;
        }
    }
} 

// Determine whether the service is running.

if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) 
{
    printf("Service started successfully.\n"); 
}
else 
{ 
    printf("Service not started. \n");
    printf("  Current State: %d\n", ssStatus.dwCurrentState); 
    printf("  Exit Code: %d\n", ssStatus.dwWin32ExitCode); 
    printf("  Check Point: %d\n", ssStatus.dwCheckPoint); 
    printf("  Wait Hint: %d\n", ssStatus.dwWaitHint); 
} 

CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a key component here: starting **Service Control Dispatcher**. As stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686953%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you have to start the service control dispatcher in order to enable Windows' **Service Control Manager (SCM)** to send commands to your service (like `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` for example)

Starting the dispatcher is done as follows:

1. create a `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` ([look at MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686001%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) containing your services' name as well as its **Service Main Function** (wich is different from your ordinary main method!)
2. start the **Service Control Dispatcher** with this service table entry

The background is that every service is being started via SCM, that waits for the service to start its [Service Control Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in order to receive its commands...

I see another problem in your code: you're trying to install your service everytime it's being started! You'd better check for appropriate command line  arguments to determine if the service is either going to be installed or started!

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that your service is either shutting down immediately or crashing. I would recommend adding some logging information to your service in order to discover why it is exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what u r tryin to do is Impersonating the remote pc. If the pc is using Windows XP, then you need priviledges other than Administrator to create services. To adjust priviledges, see the Local system policy in the remote pc. By the way, can u just open the ADMIN$ share in the remote pc from yours? if not, then this is the problem.

for further reference check psexec in sysinternals.

NO BSOD, No Rootkit ,No Fun -- Biswanath Chowdhury (Win32 Kernel Developer)